# How does one get the total number of slides?

Tags: articulate-storyline

In Articulate's Storyline product, how does one retrieve the total number of slides (or pages) in a storyfile or project?

There's not much documentation so it's kind of hard to figure out how to query common environment values like this.  If we can get the total number of slides then we don't have to manually set a value for it.

Comment: please help in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33081472/how-to-track-a-user-in-articulate-story-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One must manually set and update a variable to store the number of slides.**

The most lengthy conversation on the matter seems to be [found here at the Articulate forums](http://community.articulate.com/forums/p/22639/124303.aspx#124303).

In that thread the users and staff describe the need to manually define such a variable.

I asked the question on the official forum [more directly here](http://community.articulate.com/forums/p/36599/197312.aspx?mod=False#197312), and so far have not received a response.

Another poster at that forum mentioned using PHP to solve this problem, but unfortunately we can't add the requirement of PHP to the final product.  I'm sure some server side language tricks might be used to solve this issue, but that also adds the dependency of a particular server-side language.

Answer (score 1):

The Answer Mark gave is correct. So if you want to track the number of question slides in a quiz you would either hard code the value in a variable such as **totalQuestions**, or increment it as you go through each slide using adjust variable trigger. To call that value and display it on screen you would just add it to a text field and surround it with "%".

EG. "You have answered %Results.ScorePoints% out of %totalQuestions% questions correctly."

I find it rather pointless to hard code it since it's just as easy to put the value in the text field at the end. Using the increment method seems more logical because then you can add more question slides without having to adjust the variable or results screen each time.

Answer (score 1):

I usually load `frame.xml`, browse for all `slidelink` tags and sort all slides by their Id.

Usually you get something like `slideid=_player.5xoxGTW6QCh.6bmeRt3tCqP`, where `5xoxGTW6QCh` is the scene id and `6bmeRt3tCqP` is the slide id. `displaytext` also gives you the `slide title`.

If you browse for `slidetranscript` and match the Id for each transcript you also get the slide notes.

Answer (score 1):

Articulate 360 now has an internal (Built-in) variable for this and other counts. See Project.TotalSlides and Menu.TotalSlides

See https://community.articulate.com/series/articulate-storyline-360/articles/storyline-360-add-slide-numbers